# Bold IN List View Odoo

Tags: customization, odoo

I am trying the below code for bolding my first record and it works fine. BUt for multiple it does not

Pls guide

Code:

```
<tree string="Configuration Tree" fonts="bold:task_name == 'PLANNING AND DESIGN'">
```

and for multiple I am trying this:

```
<tree string="Configuration Tree" fonts="bold:task_name == 'PLANNING AND DESIGN' bold:task_name == 'DEVELOPMENT'">
```

The second one is not working

Guide PLz

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in` to choose from multiple values:

```
fonts="bold:task_name in ('PLANNING AND DESIGN', 'DEVELOPMENT')"
```

---

The following alternative approaches would also work, but in this particular case using `in` is preferable (as it is much clearer and shorter).

Using `or`:

```
fonts="bold:task_name == 'PLANNING AND DESIGN' or task_name == 'DEVELOPMENT'"
```

Chaning multiple rules with `;`:

```
fonts="bold:task_name == 'PLANNING AND DESIGN';bold:task_name == 'DEVELOPMENT'"
```

Comment: Thanks Ludwik.But problem is that when U export to excel why these bold lines are removed and text changes in normal? and also how can I hide one line or two lines in list view?

Comment: Formatting in data exported to Excel is a different problem, completely unrelated to your original question. You can ask another question. I don't know the answer. You can filter out particular object in list view using action's `domain` field or a default filter in search view. But that's also a separate question.